# Converting CGFloat to String in Swift

Tags: string, swift, cgfloat

This is my current way of converting a CGFloat to String in Swift:

```
let x:Float = Float(CGFloat)
let y:Int = Int(x)
let z:String = String(y)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use [string interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_425):

```
let x: CGFloat = 0.1
let string = "\(x)" // "0.1"
```

Or technically, you can use the printable nature of CGFloat directly:

```
let string = x.description
```

The `description` property comes from it implementing the `Printable` protocol which is what makes string interpolation possible.

Answer (score 20):

The fast way:

```
let x = CGFloat(12.345)
let s = String(format: "%.3f", Double(x))
```

The better way, because it takes care on locales:

```
let x = CGFloat(12.345)

let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3

let s = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me
`let newstring = floatvalue.description`